# Can I use Oauth to authenticate a Shopify private app?

Tags: shopify

How can I use Oauth to provide authentication for my private app?

I understand it's not necessary to make the actual calls, but I want to know about protecting the whole app in a way which my client doesn't need to log in twice.

If this is not possible, how do people manage their private apps?

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear

but, Here is some info

Oauth is an autherization Flow(Protocol) for end-users to authorize third-party access to their server resources without sharing their credentials(Ie. User Name and or password).

If your app is like third-party app that request user resources(ie. email or other details) from Resource servers(ie. Google , Facebook) Then Oauth is the Fittest solution.

Keep the session cookies (access Token) for avoid log in twice.